# Is there a way to define the value of a constexpr value when compiling?

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr, compile-time, compile-time-constant

When using macros, it's possible to define the value when compiling with `-D <name>=<value>`.

Can something similar to be done with `constexpr` values?

To motivate the problem, consider the following [code](https://accu.org/index.php/journals/2087) which generates a 12x12 multiplication table at compile time and prints it at run time:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ostream>
#include <array>
#include <iomanip>

template <size_t...N>
constexpr auto make_compile_time_sequence(size_t const row, std::index_sequence<N...>) {
  return std::array<size_t,sizeof...(N)> {
    {
      row*(N+1)...
    }
  };
}

template <size_t...N>
constexpr auto make_compile_time_square(std::index_sequence<N...> ){
  return std::array<std::array<size_t, sizeof...(N)>,sizeof...(N)> {
    {
      make_compile_time_sequence(N+1, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(N)>{})...
    }
  };
}

constexpr std::size_t N = 12;
constexpr auto multab_N = make_compile_time_square(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});

void testCompileTimeArray(std::ostream &out){
  std::for_each(std::begin(multab_N), std::end(multab_N),
    [&out](auto row) {
      out << '\n';
      std::for_each(std::begin(row), std::end(row), [&out](auto elt) {
        out << std::setw(4) << elt;
      });
    });
    out << '\n';
}

int main() {
    testCompileTimeArray(std::cout);
}
```

Currently `N` is hard-coded and must be changed manually to print a MxM multiplication table (where M != 12).

Is it possible to do something analogous to `-D N=<value>` with `constexpr` values?

Comment: Not possible, AFAIK. The preprocessor doesn't understand the C/C++ syntax.

Comment: `constexpr std::size_t N = N_MACRO;` with `-DN_MACRO=12` will do the trick, although it kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That's basically the work-around I came up with, as well. :)

Comment: If you use cmake or something like that, you can easily automate everything.